# How do I get the path to a file from my current directory?

Tags: java, path

I'm reading in a file, the problem is that I can read anything in my own directory, and anything in any sub-directories, however when I use `.getPath()` It gives me the full path from route e.g. `C:\Users\smandre\Documents\file.txt`. How can I use this path to read in a file from my program? I've also tried `.getCanonicalPath()

```
int returnVal = c.showOpenDialog(c);

        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            setFilePath(c.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFilePath()));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + c.getSelectedFile().getPath());

            // System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(getFilePath()));
            return;
        }
```

Obviously the above is trying to open the file path starting from my system route, not from my current directory...

Comment: Are you looking for `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`? That will load your files relative to your _classpath_ instead of the root of the filesystem, or your current working directory.

Comment: your own directory is your project's base? show us the code you are using

Comment: Related: [How to get the path of a running jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/320542/335858).

Comment: What exactly are you asking? From "How can I use this path..." it sounds like you've **got** the path to a file which you wish to read, but this doesn't really conform to the title. Please provide a more complete explanation, and preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: saw your edit. Still not clear what is exactly your problem? Wrong file is opened? Some error occurs?

Comment: When you open a file in Java, you must specify the entire path from the root of the file system.  You don't need access to those folders to use them in a file path.  When you construct the FileReader on the full path, it should work correctly.  If it does not, please specify the error you receive.